# Zapier Python oder NodeJS extraction of data

Tags: python, node.js, zapier

I need to extract a pairs of substrings from a string in zapier with nodejs or python. Zapier uses Regex expressions and the output is specific. The output is in xfdf format.

Javascript documentation: https://zapier.com/help/code/

Python documentation: https://zapier.com/help/code-python/

```
@name: Label Vorname
value: Vorname Teilnehmer
@name: Label Geschlecht
value: Geschlecht Teilnehmer
@name: Label Adresse
value: Straße und Hausnummer
@name: Label Geburtstag
value: Geburtstag Teilnehmer
@name: Label Notfall Name
value: Name Notfallkontakt
@name: Label Email
value: Email des Unterschreibenden
@name: Text Newsletter
value: Ich möchte mich zum kostenlosen Newsletter anmelden. Ja, bitte informieren Sie mich über die neusten News des Parkour Creation e.V.. Die Abmeldung ist jederzeit möglich.
@name: Label Ort
value: Ort
@name: Label Telefon
value: Telefonnummer Notfallkontakt
@name: Label PLZ
value: PLZ
@name: Label Nachname
value: Nachname Teilenhmer
@name: Label Telefon Notfall
value: Telefonnummer Notfallkontakt
@name: Text Datenschutz
value: Ja, ich stimme den Datenschutzbestimmungen des Parkour Creation e.V zu.
@name: Hamburg
value: Hamburg,
@name: Label Unterschreiber
value: Name des Unterschreibenden
@name: Vorname Teilnehmer
value: Letzter
@name: Adresse
value: Die Straße 13b
@name: Geschlecht
value: weiblich
@name: Telefon
value: 12345678
@name: Nachname Teilnehmer
value: Test
@name: EmailAddress
value: mchl.schd@gmail.com
@name: Name Notfall
value: Der Beste
@name: Ort
value: Hamburg
@name: Tele Notfall
value: 87654321
@name: Datenschutzbestimmungen
value: Optionsfeld1
@name: PLZ
value: 20015
@name: FullName
value: Der Letzte
@name: Newsletter
value: X
@name: Bday Datum
value: 01/01/2000
@name: DateSigned
value: 28. April 2019 | 20:01 CEST
@name: Unter18
value: 19.33
@name: Prüfen
value: 0
```

I need to extract the value as follows to use in next steps:

```
@name Name Notfall
value: Der Beste
```

--> Name Notfall: { Der Beste }

Further steps are to dynamically pair the output values with new input values in the next step.

Comment: Can you share some of what you have attempted thus far? What is your familiarity with either Python or Javascript? How is the information being funneled into your code step?

Comment: Hey Michael,
I have tried several attempts with python to find the string looking through the lines with re.match multiline "@name: Name Notfall value: " without success. Also I have tried to extract all values after ":" and then combine them with the previous extraction value with a comma: "Name Notfall, Der Beste" but I cant seem to get them in correct format for future use.

It is funneled through a simple string input.

Answer (score -1):

this task seems like CPU intensive, I would suggest Python

Comment: you can use JSON, "key value pair".

{
 "name": "Notfall",
  "value": "Der Beste"

}

Comment: That does not really help, as I mentioned I need to extract all the pairs in the string dynamically.